# how to check multiple dates between startdate and enddate in query c#

Tags: c#, mysql, date

Working in c#.
I have two date object named `start_date_entered` and `end_date_entered` and I have two columns in my table `start_date` and `end_date`. I have to query my table that if any of the dates between `start_date_entered` and `end_date_entered` are present in between `start_date` and `end_date`.

```
DateTime start_date_entered = Convert.ToDateTime('01/01/2018 12:00:00 AM');
DateTime end_date_entered = Convert.ToDateTime('03/01/2018 12:00:00 AM');
```

the database column start_date contains let say 25th march and end_date contains 27th march. If the both sequences have any date common then no row should be returned from the database. If there is any common date between both sequences then database should return the row.

```
select * from employee_leaves where ... between start_date and end_date
```

what should i write in "..." as I want to put a sequence of dates between `start_date_entered` and `end_date_entered` here

I have tried these,

[Fetching Dates Which Comes Between StartDate and EndDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216991/fetching-dates-which-comes-between-startdate-and-enddate)

[How to list all dates between two dates [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529860/how-to-list-all-dates-between-two-dates)

But haven't find any solution.

Comment: _But haven't find any solution_ What didn't work as you expected?

Comment: Can you give some example input data and expected output?

Comment: my query is incomplete. I am not getting a way how to write the whole sequence in the where I placed "..."

Comment: I have made some edits @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're querying for everything that intersects a given time range (start/end) - try visualizing all the possibilities of things you want to include; for example:

```
       |<--range-->|
       |           |
   [---+-----------+----]          scenario 1 - starts before, ends after
       |   [---]   |               scenario 2 - starts and ends inside
       |   [-------+-----------]   scenario 3 - starts inside, ends after
   [---+-------]   |               scenario 4 - starts before, ends inside
       |           |
```

Scenarios 2, 3, and 4 will be handled by checking whether *either* end is in the query; scenario 1 needs to be handled separately; so:

```
where x.Start between @start and @end
   or x.End between @start and @end
   or (x.Start < @start and x.End > @end)
```

Note that `between` is an *inclusive* range query; if you need more control of the boundary conditions, expand `between` to an explicit pair of start/end limits with your choice of inequality operators.

Comment: for any of the 4 scenarios, no row should be returned from database.

Comment: @FarrukhSarmad fine; I don't understand why not, but whatever - not my problem; you know the rules about which rows **you want** to return - so: draw the equivalent map for the things you want to include and exclude, and from that determine the appropriate `where` filter for your needs; the example here - while being what most people usually want when doing a date-range query over entities with a date-range - was meant to be illustrative, not definitive

Comment: there is a leave for an employee in the database that is approved. I want to restrict the user to again request for a leave for the same dates he has already approved.

Comment: @FarrukhSarmad great; so draw out the table for what you want, and implement the corresponding `where` query... frankly, it seems to me that the code I've already posted will find any leave scheduled for the range in question, so I'm not sure how the code I've posted isn't a 100% fit.

Comment: I modifies it with my vareiables so your code is returning a row if any of the date resides. Now when I read it in the dataReader object if dr.Read() will return true then I will prompt the user that your entered date has already been approved for a leave :)

Comment: See also [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325933/18192).  You can check scenarios 1-4 in only two comparisons.