# Getting dates between startdate and enddate from array in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

As I am new to swift, I stuck here from very longer,I am trying to get date from array between start date and end date,.

I have tried these code which refered from `[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216991/fetching-dates-which-comes-between-startdate-and-enddate], But I am getting the error as "Value of type '[Date]' has no member 'filtered'".`

In swift

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF > %@) AND (SELF < %@)", startdate!, enddate!)
var result = arrayWithDates.filtered(using: predicate)

Expected output: 
dateArray = ["12/01/1996","13/01/1996","15/01/1996","17/01/1996"]
startdate = "13/01/1996" 
enddate = "17/01/1996"
output = ["13/01/1996","15/01/1996","17/01/1996"]
```

please help me to acheive this, thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587796/10150796

Comment: @Nikunj Kumbhani  thanks for ur response, actually this is not my case, I need to get the dates from [Dates], not from calender.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Already i have mentioned in my question, i have used the same code but am getting error as  "Value of type '[Date]' has no member 'filtered'"

Comment: @Swift_prasad I know but you can put the condition as per your expectation while appending the date in **mydates** array

Comment: @Swift_prasad Try nikunj answer.. Its working I guess and hope below answer is also working.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Below Answer am getting output which is not even in my array.

Comment: @Swift_prasad You can refer my answer for net and clean code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
import Foundation

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")

let dateArray = ["12/01/1996","13/01/1996","15/01/1996","17/01/1996"]
let startdate = dateFormatter.date(from: "13/01/1996")!
let enddate = dateFormatter.date(from: "17/01/1996")!

let output = dateArray
    // Map your strings to Date objects excluding nils.
    .compactMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }
    // Filter the mapped array by your condition.
    .filter { $0 >= startdate && $0 <= enddate }
```

Comment: @Mo Abdul-Hameed thanks for your response, But am getting irrelevant output.

Comment: @Swift_prasad Sorry, I updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: Parse `startDate` and `endDate` only once, not during every iteration. Use `compactMap` instead of `map` and `!`.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you very much for your notes, you're completely right. I updated the answer based on them.

Comment: @Swift_prasad I updated my answer based on Sulthan's notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, it works for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var arrDates = NSArray()
var arrResultDates = NSMutableArray()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   arrDates = ["12/01/1996","13/01/1996","15/01/1996","17/01/1996"]
    let strStartDate = "\(arrDates.firstObject!)"
    let strEndDate = "\(arrDates.lastObject!)"
    let formatter  = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    //Get start date
    var startDate = formatter.date(from: strStartDate)
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: strEndDate) // last date

    // Formatter for printing the date, adjust it according to your needs:
    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    while startDate! <= endDate! {

        startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate!)!
        let strDate = fmt.string(from: startDate!)
        if arrDates.contains(strDate)
        {
            arrResultDates.add(strDate)
        }
    }

    print(arrResultDates)

}
```

Hope it will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `NSPredicate` you have to bridge the array to `NSArray` which responds to `filtered(using:`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF > %@) AND (SELF < %@)", startdate!, enddate!)
let result = (arrayWithDates as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate)
```

However in the world of Swift this is not recommended. Just use the `filter` function with a closure

```
let result = arrayWithDates.filter { $0 >= startdate! && $0 <= enddate! }
```